# How to schedule a LocalNotification that repeats only one time in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I'm creating a local notification inside one of my ViewController.

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
```

I set it's scheduled time after 30 seconds, for my testing purposes.

```
localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:30];
```

I've added some more properties for that local notification

```
    localNotification.alertBody = @"Alert message";
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
```

After all I schedule the notification.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

As I planned the notification fired in 30 seconds.

Now what I need is, repeat that notification one more time after one minute. It is like a pre defined snooze time.

If I add ***repeatInterval*** property, like below, then it will fire in every one minute.

```
localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitMinute;
```

Is there any way to achieve my target?

As a summary, what I need is fire a local notification in ***fireDate*** value and only one another pre defined snooze time even the application in background and phone is locked.

Note : Please do not suggest to create one another local notification for this.

Comment: You need to schedule 2 notification with fire date and another is firedate + 1 minute. When you tap on notification then manually remove second notification. Otherwise both notification fire one by one on specific fire date.

Comment: Notifications either repeat or they don't.  There is no capability to specify a number of repeats

Comment: @YagneshDobariya I think you haven't noticed my _Note_ part. I'm searching an option other than this.

Answer (score 1):

Set `localNotification.repeatInterval = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

you can set `userInfo` in notification,

```
NSMutableDictionary *payload = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
payload[@"repeat"] = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
payload[@"interval"] = @(1.0);
```

after setting notification, add user info to it

```
....
localNotification.alertBody = @"Alert message";
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
....
localNotification.userInfo = payload;
```

and in `didReceiveLocalNotification` delegate method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
     NSDictionary *dict = [notification userInfo];
     BOOL repeat = [dict[@"repeat"] boolValue];
     if (repeat) {
          //update firedate and schedule notification
     }
}
```

Comment: Clever solution.

Comment: @Akhilrajtr I already tried that alternative. This will not work when phone is locked. Which means to fire didReceiveLocalNotification method, either application should in foreground or user has to tap on the first notification alert.

Comment: @AnujAroshA ohk. in that case, i can't think of any other solution other than adding 2 notifications. may be someone here can help. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

@Akhilrajtr's solution is almost correct.

You could update notification's User info and handle it in `didReceiveLocalNotification`. And in addition to this, You need to **register Notification settings**.

**AppDelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    return YES;
}
```

> NB: `UIUserNotificationSettings` is Deprecated in iOS 10. Use
>   [UNNotificationSettings](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationsettings) instead.

**Solution:**

1.Add userInfo to Notification Object

```
localNotification.userInfo = @{@"repeat" : @(YES), @"interval" : @(1.f)};
```

2.Update the Schedule time in `didReceiveLocalNotification`

Answer (score -2):

You should call a method after a minute of first `notification` and that will fire another `notification` just once.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0
    target:self
    selector:@selector(targetMethod:)
    userInfo:nil
    repeats:NO];
```